# How to make the text fill up the UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, button

I have a button named `btn`

```
btn.titleLabel = @"balabalabala";
```

I found that the `btn.frame` is `(0,0,100,30)`,and the `btn.titleLabel.frame` is `(12,6,75,18)`.So I get the btn with ba...labala.

How to make the text fill up the button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the button's label and set the label up to auto adjust its font.

```
[btn setTitle:@"balabalabala" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UILabel *lbl = btn.titleLabel;
lbl.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: anyway to do this in the attribute inspector or option on the xcode gui?